# Python optimization search pythagorean triplets

Tags: python, performance

I have an optimization problem. Be it about code, algorithm or maths, that, i don't know.
My goal is to find pythagorean triplets satisfying a = b + 1 or a = b - 1.
m and n are the triplets generators.
The following code produces the desired output, but it's not fast enough from about the 11th or 12th item.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

from time import perf_counter
import numpy as np
from numba import njit, prange
import json, os

@njit
def isPythagoreanTriplet(x:int, y:int) -> bool:
    """
    Test if a and b are a valid basis for a pythagorean triplet
    """
    return (abs(2*x - y) == 1)

@njit
def findNextPythagoreanTriplet(n:int)->tuple[int]:
    """
    Self-explanatory function name
    """
    m = 4 * n
    while True:
        for n in prange(1, m):
            m_sq = m * m
            n_sq = n * n
            a = m_sq - n_sq
            b = 2 * m * n 
            c = m_sq + n_sq
            if isPythagoreanTriplet(a, b):
                return(2*a, b, c, m, n)
            elif isPythagoreanTriplet(b, a):
                return(a, 2*b, c, m, n)
        m+= 1


def pythagoreanTriplets(compteur:int, n:int=1)->None : 
    """
    Find compteur pythagorean triplets
    """
    while compteur :
        a, b, c, m, n = findNextPythagoreanTriplet(n)
        store(a, b, c, m, n)
        n = m
        compteur-= 1
  
def store(a,b,c, m, n):
    """
    Store a pythagorean triplet and its generators in a text file
    """
    with open("results.txt", "a") as file_out:
        file_out.write(f"{a} {b} {c} {m} {n}\n")

def init_n()->tuple[int]:
    """
    Check if result text file exists to start from last stop for n
    """
    nb_lignes = 0
    n = 1
    if os.path.exists("results.txt"):
        with open("results.txt", "r") as file_in:
            lines = file_in.readlines()
            for line in lines:
                line = line.strip()
                if line:
                    nb_lignes+= 1
                    _, _, _, m, n = line.split()
                n = m
    
    return (nb_lignes, int(n))
    
  
# Driver Code 
if __name__ == '__main__' : 
    nb_items = 12
    start = perf_counter()
    nb_lignes, n = init_n()
    nb_items-= nb_lignes
    print(f"Nb items restants : {nb_items}")
    pythagoreanTriplets(nb_items, n)
    stop = perf_counter()
    duree = stop - start
    print(f"Durée : {duree:.2f}s")
```

Comment: Micro-review: PEP-8 recommends snake_case for function names.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're coming at this with the wrong algorithm.

Given a right triangle with sides a, b and (hypotenuse) a+1, we have:

$$ a² + b² = (a+1)² $$

So

$$ b² = (a+1)² - a² $$
$$ = a² + 2a + 1 - a² $$
$$ = 2a + 1 $$

From this, we can deduce that for any odd length for *b* (*b* > 1), we can find a corresponding *a* and therefore the other two sides.

Using that algorithm, I have this generator (lacking docstring and type annotations):

```
def generate_triplets():
    b = 1
    while True:
       b += 2
       a = b * b // 2
       yield (a, b, a+1)
```

Simple demo:

```
import itertools
for triangle in itertools.islice(generate_triplets(), 50):
    print(triangle)
```